# Stray decimal values in real numbers

Tags: floating-point, verilog, system-verilog

I have a real number `delay` which I would like to convert to the first multiple of 10. For example, if delay = 0.0024, I want the output to be 240.

In the following code snippet, `delay` = 1.52e-6. After `while` loop execution, I was expecting `delay` to be 1520. However, I'm seeing that `delay` = 1.52e17 after `while` loop. I checked the waveform, and it looks like the value of `delay` was 1.5200000000000001e-6 to begin with. Why is it so?  Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code:

```
  real delay = 1.52e-6;

  function real mod (real a, real b);
      mod = a - b*$floor(a/b);
  endfunction

  initial begin
      while (mod(delay, 10) != 0) delay = delay*10;
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the following code snippet, delay = 1.52e-6

Note quite.

Floating point types are commonly encoded using [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) or the like.  This 64-bit encoding can encode about 2<sup>64</sup> different values exactly.  1.52e-6 is **not** one of them as it is not a [Dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) (some integer times a power of 2).  Instead code starts working with a nearby value of 1.5200000000000000582720720634921640623815619619563e-06 or 0x198059AC99A685 * 2<sup>-72</sup>.

Further complications occurs because many of the `delay = delay*10` incur a rounding error.

Amend goal or use a different approach.

"convert to the first multiple of 10" sounds like a secondary goal.  What is the higher level goal?

Note:  All finite floating point values are *exact*.  It is how we operate on them that often leading to a result that differs from the exact math result we learned in school.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it so?

You can see why this happens if you `$display` intermediate values when you run your simulation.  It will be more obvious than looking at a waveform, which will only show you the final value after the `while` loop completes.  Here is a runnable code example:

```
module tb;
real delay = 1.52e-6;

function real mod (real a, real b);
    mod = a - b*$floor(a/b);
    $display("a=%g, floor=%g, mod=%g", a, $floor(a/b), mod);
endfunction

initial begin
    $display(delay);
    while (mod(delay, 10) != 0) delay = delay*10;
    $display(delay);
end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
1.52e-06
a=1.52e-06, floor=0, mod=1.52e-06
a=1.52e-05, floor=0, mod=1.52e-05
a=0.000152, floor=0, mod=0.000152
a=0.00152, floor=0, mod=0.00152
a=0.0152, floor=0, mod=0.0152
a=0.152, floor=0, mod=0.152
a=1.52, floor=0, mod=1.52
a=15.2, floor=1, mod=5.2
a=152, floor=15, mod=2
a=1520, floor=152, mod=2.27374e-13
a=15200, floor=1520, mod=1.81899e-12
a=152000, floor=15200, mod=2.91038e-11
a=1.52e+06, floor=152000, mod=2.32831e-10
a=1.52e+07, floor=1.52e+06, mod=1.86265e-09
a=1.52e+08, floor=1.52e+07, mod=2.98023e-08
a=1.52e+09, floor=1.52e+08, mod=2.38419e-07
a=1.52e+10, floor=1.52e+09, mod=1.90735e-06
a=1.52e+11, floor=1.52e+10, mod=3.05176e-05
a=1.52e+12, floor=1.52e+11, mod=0.000244141
a=1.52e+13, floor=1.52e+12, mod=0.00195312
a=1.52e+14, floor=1.52e+13, mod=0.03125
a=1.52e+15, floor=1.52e+14, mod=0.25
a=1.52e+16, floor=1.52e+15, mod=2
a=1.52e+17, floor=1.52e+16, mod=0
1.52e+17
```

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yes.  The problem is that your comparison check in the `while` loop did not work the way you expected it to work.  You should not compare  `real` values to 0 like that.  Instead, you need to compare it to some reasonably small tolerance value.  For example:

```
while (mod(delay, 10) > 1e-12) delay = delay*10;
```

This gives you the desired output: `1520`

Here is the full output:

```
1.52e-06
a=1.52e-06, floor=0, mod=1.52e-06
a=1.52e-05, floor=0, mod=1.52e-05
a=0.000152, floor=0, mod=0.000152
a=0.00152, floor=0, mod=0.00152
a=0.0152, floor=0, mod=0.0152
a=0.152, floor=0, mod=0.152
a=1.52, floor=0, mod=1.52
a=15.2, floor=1, mod=5.2
a=152, floor=15, mod=2
a=1520, floor=152, mod=2.27374e-13
1520
```

There is **uncertainty** with all floating-point variable types.  Sometimes, a direct comparison like `!=` will work, and other times it will not work.  It is not guaranteed to work, which is why a tolerance value helps.

This is a general issue with [floating-point comparison](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).